# Meaning of this declaration count[array[i]]

Tags: c++, c

Can any one explain me what is the meant by `count[array[i]]` in the following program? 
the purpose of the code is to Print all the Repeated Numbers with Frequency in an Array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void duplicate(int array[], int num)
{
    int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), (num - 2));
    int i;

    printf("duplicate elements present in the given array are ");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (count[array[i]] == 1)
            printf(" %d ", array[i]);
        else
            count[array[i]]++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {5, 10, 10, 2, 1, 4, 2};
    int array_freq = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    duplicate(array, array_freq);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `array[i]` do? What does `count[someIndex]` do? Put them together. That's also not a declaration.

Comment: `count[array[i]]++;` can be re-written as: `int t = array[i]; count[t]++;`. Does it help?

Comment: It is used to find the duplicates inside an array

Comment: I rolled the last edit back. The question had been completely changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the worse method used to find duplicates in an array.

```
count[array[i]]++;
```

So, `array[i]` will return the number at that index which would in-turn serve as index for count array. For e.g:-

```
array[4] = {1,2,3,1};
```

Iterating array into this will be like:-

```
count[array[0]] = count[1] = 1;
count[array[1]] = count[2] = 1;
count[array[2]] = count[3] = 1;
count[array[3]] = count[1] = 2; << Increment the count...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right. You are trying to print all duplicates in a given array.
First, you create an array count and fill it with zeros.

```
int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), (num - 2));
```

if count[x] equals 0 than it means that number x is not presented in the array.
if count[x] equals 1 than it means that there is only one instance of x in the array.
if count[x] greater then 1 than it means that there is more then one instance of x in the array.

So you go through the given array and update count array. Simultaniously with updating you are checking if there were any duplicates. That is what these lines do:

```
if (count[array[i]] == 1)
    printf(" %d ", array[i]);
else
    count[array[i]]++;
```

From my point of view it is not the best way to do a such routine. Two problems I can see now are : you don't free count array and the size of count array must be bigger then any number in a given array. As another solution you try to think how to accomplish this task with std::set or std::unique function.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed has no sense. For example the first parameter of function `calloc` is the number of elements that have to be allocated. However in your code the corresponding argument is `sizeof(int)` that usually equal to 4. The second parameter of the function is the size of the element. But in the program there is specified `num - 2`(?). Though calloc allocates one extent of memory that equal to the product of the first argument by the second argument nevertheless it is totally unclear why there is used `num - 2`.

As for this expression `count[array[i]]`  then it is an obvious bug. The value of array[i] can be much greater than the number of allocated elements in the dynamic memory.

For it will be clear you can logically split this expression into two. For example

```
int j = array[i];
count[j];
```

For example for array

```
int array[] = {5, 10, 10, 2, 1, 4, 2};
```

`array[1]` is equal to 10. Thus `count[array[i]]` is equivalent to `count[10]` But there was allocated only `num - 2` elements pointed to by count. As `num - 2` in this particular case is equal to 5 then count[10] is a non-exsistent element of the array.

Take into account that in general case you need free dynamically allocated memory.

I think you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void duplicate( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t *count;
    int i;

    if ( n < 2 ) return;

    count = ( size_t * )calloc( n - 1, sizeof( size_t ) );

    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < i && a[i] != a[j] ) j++;

        if ( j != i ) ++count[j];
    }

    printf( "duplicate elements present in the given array are " );
    for ( i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ )
    {
        if ( count[i] )
        {
            printf( " %d ", a[i] );
        }
    }

    free( count );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 5, 10, 10, 2, 1, 4, 2 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    duplicate( a, n );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
duplicate elements present in the given array are  10  2
```

If to substitute statement

```
printf( " %d ", a[i] );
```

for

```
printf( " %d(%zu) ", a[i], count[i] + 1 );
```

then the output will be

```
duplicate elements present in the given array are  10(2)  2(2)
```

If you will use my code then please do not forget to mark my answer as the best.:)